# How to create or generate this pattern in sql server( or in asp.net ) for reference ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create reference Id , which has the following pattern and store it in 
in `referenceID` column at `tblReferences` table

First month

```
   H01C01001L  
   H01C01002L 
   ...
   H01C01102L
```

after a month the pattern repeats like this,

```
  H01C02001L  
  H01C02002L 
   ...
  H01C02102L
```

third month:

```
  H01C03001L  
  H01C03002L 
   ...
  H01C03102L
```

`H01` `C`, and `L` will not change

upper limit for the sequence in pattern is unknown, but it will stop between `200` and `400` in a month

i am new to sql databases, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What event should generate the pattern, on insert, bulk update start/end of month or something else? BTW the H01C and L bits seem irrelevant since they never change.

Comment: just to create/insert record in tblreferences upon a request from user thorough asp.net page(     ReferenceNumber, , SignedBy ) fields. the H01C and L bits must be there on the id they are required

Comment: So, it will be an one-time insert query, starting with an empty `tblReferences`?

Comment: A change to my comment may have crossed with you reply so I'll ask again -  H01C and L bits seem irrelevant since they never change

Comment: if your only aim is to keep a unique identifier then you can make the field of type `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and you can assign values to the function using `NEWID()`

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis yes, insert query upon request

Comment: @P.Salmon Nope the former part changes with month but the L stands still

Comment: @SanalSunny the requirement is that it should follow given pattern

Comment: What's the next value after month " H12C" at the end of that month?

Comment: @JonTout i have edited, `H01` and `L` will not change

Comment: upper limit is `H01C99999L`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled it will stop somewhere between 200 -400 a month

Comment: Is month simply the number of the month in the current year? If so, what happens when the new year starts?

Comment: @The Scientific Method the format is H01CmmsegnoL, where mm is the month of what exactly -date of insert perhaps?

Comment: @P.Salmon exactly you are right

Comment: 'H01 and L will not change' which means C can change to what?

Comment: @P.Salmon C also will not change

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to achieve that. Just create a new one that starts with your first number:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.NumbersSequence AS INT START WITH 1001 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

When you need to generate a new reference ID, obtain the next number from the sequence and format it to match your pattern:

```
declare @number int
select @number = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.NumbersSequence;
select CONCAT('N01C', FORMAT(@number, 'D5'), 'L')
```

When you need to change the next value that will be generated (i.e. next month), alter the sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.NumbersSequence RESTART WITH 2001;
```

Comment: thanks but i have two sequences on the pattern one for the month 01, 02, 03 the other 001, 0002, ..

Comment: And if a record ever fails to insert or simply deleted you will have gaps in the numbers....

Comment: @TheScientificMethod In this case your sequence will always start from 1 when created or restarted and you need to change the format to be 3 digits (from D5 to D3). How you will determine the month? It isn't a sequence I believe. It is either a configuration, or it is the current month (in which case you can get is as DATEPART(month, getdate()) or something like that)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach this. I assume a source table called `sourcetable`, having a date field named `datefield`:

```
insert into tblReferences (referenceID,...(other cols)...)
    select
        'H01C'
        +convert(char(2),q2.monthindex)
        +convert(char(3),row_number() over (partition by q2.monthindex order by s.datefield asc))
        +'L' as referenceID,
        ...(other cols)...
from sourcetable s
cross join (select min(s2.datefield) as firstdate from sourcetable s2)q1  -- gets first date to compare others
cross apply(select datediff(month,q1.firstdate ,s.datefield as monthindex)q2 -- gets month difference between first and current
```

You may run the query without the first (insert) line to make sure it produces what you want. As others have commented, this won't work for more than a year, returning values like H01C13001L and so on.